# Weird date format, I'm getting added leading zeros before two-digit year stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, formatting, date-format

I'm working on a Laravel 5.5 app with MySQL database running in Laragon.

My date stored in my database turns two-digit years (e.g. "15") into four-digit numbers with leading zeros (e.g. "0015"). If my user enters 2/1/12 for February 1st, 2012, then 2/1/0012 is stored in the database.

I have a validation rule in a request as follows:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        /* 'liability_last_payment_date' => 'nullable|date_format:'.config('app.date_format'), */
        'liability_last_payment_date' => 'nullable|date_multi_format:"m/d/Y","mm/dd/yy","MM/DD/YYYY"', 
        'liability_account_balance' => 'nullable|numeric',
    ];
}
```

I've adjusted the formats to no avail.

My controller doesn't address the format and the MySQL database field is simply DATE format.

Here's my controller code:

```
   public function update(UpdateInstallmentsDebtsLiabilitiesRequest $request, $id)
   {
       if (! Gate::allows('installments_debts_liability_edit')) {
           return abort(401);
       }
       $installments_debts_liability = InstallmentsDebtsLiability::findOrFail($id);

       $installments_debts_liability->update($request->all());

       return redirect()->back(); //return redirect()->route('admin.installments_debts_liabilities.index');
   }
```

Not sure why the date is being stored this way, but suspect the validation rule (just because this issue came up after I changed the validation formatting) but can't trace the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First of all the date formats you are writing over here is wrong
It takes the regular PHP date string formatters : https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: so the format would be only `m/d/y` if date is `12/22/15` and `m/d/Y` if it is `12/22/2015`

Comment: also, if you parse the date from `m/d/y` php will automatically add the full year as per given in the link above.

Comment: So try to add after parsing.

Comment: Thanks Dhaval, but not sure I understand. I don't think it's the validation format I'm using because If I only use m/d/y (or any other format) I still get the same result. The controller isn't parsing that I can see. Are you suggesting I manually-format the date in the controller and stuff that back into the field value? Or where do you suggest I modify the code? - thank you for the assistance.

Comment: you have to modify date before doing this `$installments_debts_liability->update($request->all());` because database does not understand whether to put 19 or 20 for full year.

Comment: and in database `date` type column must have 4 digit year.

Comment: I had tried that originally but the date from the form is not yet evaluated before that line. For example, when I do: ```$installments_debts_liability = InstallmentsDebtsLiability::findOrFail($id);
        dd($installments_debts_liability->liability_last_payment_date);
        $installments_debts_liability->update($request->all());``` it gives me the value already in the database, not what the user just entered. Moving the ```dd()``` line to after the ```->update($request->all()); ```shows the correct entry, but too late to intervene to change format.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the date like this before updating

```
$input = $request->all();
if (!empty($input['liability_last_payment_date'])) {
    $new_date = date_create_from_format("m/d/y",$input['liability_last_payment_date']);
    $input['liability_last_payment_date'] = $new_date->format("Y-m-d");
}
$installments_debts_liability->update($input);
```